# How to view request response for non Ajax Calls

Tags: html, debugging, browser

I am working on a Web based application where the user interface is made using Jquery and the backend was developed using Java / Java EE.

On the user interface once I click on the submit button, the request goes and 
the response comes from the back end. (This is not an AJAX call)

Is it possible to see what data went as request and how the response came back from the back end? Are there any such tools to view the request / response if it's not an AJax Call?

By the way I am using Chrome and Apple browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Network tab of Web Inspector (Chrome/WebKit) or Web Console (Firefox) or the Net tab (Firefox with Firebug)

Comment: Lie Ryan , the Network tab of Web Inspector only displays Ajax Calls details , and for the Web Console i need to know what js file it is and in which i am not sure .

Comment: @Kiran: the Network tab shows all requests made by the browser, both Ajax and non Ajax. If you only need to see the JavaScript file though, the Source tab would also be just as useful.

Answer (score 0):

Another option than using a browsers native network inspector (which btw DOES work for non-Ajax requests), is to use an intercepting proxy.

[Burp Proxy](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html) is particular nice. It allows you to see, hold and if needed modify both the request and the response between the browser and the server. You do need to setup your browser to use a proxy. It has a somewhat steeper learning curve than the browser's native network inspectors, but once you get the hang of it it's quite an invaluable tool.